# Overriding region theme file for user profile pages

Tags: users, theming

I am on D7 using Omega as a base theme. The `<h1>` tag of my theme can be found in the **region--content.tpl.php** theme file.

But I want to override this theme in one specific situation: on the user profile pages, I don't want the title to be set on **region--content.tpl.php**. I will take care of the title on the **user-profile.tpl.php** theme file. So what I want is a theme file that will override the custom default region theme file in the specific situation where user profiles are being viewed. That theme won't have a title set in it.

I have tried creating specific themes called **region--content--user.tpl.php** and **region--content--user-profile.tpl.php**, but they didn't override the default **region--content.tpl.php** theme. Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I found solution on this blog http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2012/05/10/drupal-7-customize-region-template-file-for-specific-content-type/
and here is my code to suggest a user profile region.

```
    function YOURTHEME_alpha_preprocess_region(&$vars) {
      $menu_object = menu_get_object();
      if (isset($menu_object->type) && $vars['region'] == 'content') {
        $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'region__content__'.$menu_object->type;
        $vars['attributes_array']['class'][] = 'region-content-'.$menu_object->type;
      }
//theme suggestion for user profile
      elseif ($vars['region'] == 'content' && $vars['elements']["system_main"] && $vars['elements']["system_main"]["#entity_type"] == 'user') {
        $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'region__content__userprofile';
        $vars['attributes_array']['class'][] = 'region-content-userprofile';
      }
    }
```